# How to check time between 2 date variables in php?

Tags: php

i have 3 variables with 3 numbers (day, year, month)
they all become together to a date type variable.
also, i have a date variable with the current day.

how do i check if the first date is 13 or less years before the current one?
here's my code:

```
$usersday = (int)$_POST['day']; 
$usersyear = (int)$_POST['year']; 
$usersmonth = (int)$_POST['month'];
$takedate = date_create("$usersyear-$usersmonth-$usersday");
$date = date_format($takedate, 'd-m-Y');
$currentDate = date('Y-m-d');
```

Comment: parse current date and compare the date, month & year with user data.
Use regex to parse the data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`date_*()` functions and `date()` are, confusingly, parts of two different Date library APIs. The the object-oriented version of `date_*()` functions clarifies it a bit, as well as being a more robust library. Eg:

```php
$usersyear = 2001;
$usersmonth = 1;
$usersday = 1;

$takedate = new DateTime("$usersyear-$usersmonth-$usersday");
$today    = new DateTime('today');
$diff     = $today->diff($takedate);

var_dump($diff, $diff->y);
```

Output

```
object(DateInterval)#3 (10) {
  ["y"]=>
  int(22)
  ["m"]=>
  int(7)
  ["d"]=>
  int(15)
  ["h"]=>
  int(0)
  ["i"]=>
  int(0)
  ["s"]=>
  int(0)
  ["f"]=>
  float(0)
  ["invert"]=>
  int(1)
  ["days"]=>
  int(8262)
  ["from_string"]=>
  bool(false)
}
int(22)
```

Ref: https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.datetime.php

Answer (score 0):

I don't about knowdeg php. But it will work to compare the data:

```
<?php
// Online PHP compiler to run PHP program online
$pattern = "/(\d{4})-(\d{2})-(\d{2})/";


// user input date
$usersday = 12; // (int)$_POST['day']; 
$usersyear = 2021; // (int)$_POST['year']; 
$usersmonth = 1; // (int)$_POST['month'];
$takedate = date_create("$usersyear-$usersmonth-$usersday");
$date = date_format($takedate, 'Y-m-d');
// date to string format
$userDateString = $takedate->format('Y-m-d');
echo "\n $userDateString";
echo "\n User Data: Year: $usersyear, Month: $usersmonth, Day: $usersday";

// currrent date to string
$cdate = new DateTime();
$currentDateString = $cdate->format('Y-m-d');
echo "\n$currentDateString";

if (preg_match($pattern, $currentDateString, $matches)) {
    $cyear = $matches[1];
    $cmonth = $matches[2];
    $cday = $matches[3];
}

echo "\n Current Data: Year: $cyear, Month: $cmonth, Day: $cday";
// Add your condition to compare data
?>
```